# Hover and Focus need together

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-hover, onfocus

i am trying to show the span when hover in and focus in .but i am unable bind both methods together.
Here is the code a snippet. Every help or guidance should be appreciated :)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#101").hover(
  function(){ $("#spn1").css("color", "red").show();
   });


   $("#101").focusin(function(){
    $("spn1").css("color", "red").show();
  });
  $("#101").focusout(function(){
    $("#spn1").css("color", "red").hide();
  });

});
</script>


<input type="text" id="101"><span style="display:none;" id="spn1">limit 0-100</span>
```

Comment: Whats your expected ouput?,By the way you are missing # on     $("spn1").css("color", "red").show();

Comment: I  want that  after hover out span did not disappear when I clicked or writing inside text box .@Vimal

Comment: I have added a answer,Is that What you want?

Answer (score 0):

`hover` method is not delegated . It's bind. So you can't use like:

```
$('#101').on('hover focus', function () {
    // your stuff
});
```

So you have only option to chained the method like below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#101').hover(function() {
    $("#spn1").css("color", "red").show();
  }).on('focus',
    function() {
      $("#spn1").css("color", "red").show();
    });
  $("#101").focusout(function() {
    $("#spn1").css("color", "red").hide();
  }).on('mouseleave',
    function() {
      $("#spn1").css("color", "red").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="101"><span style="display:none;" id="spn1">limit 0-100</span>
```

Comment: It is working same as mine nothing different @shree

Comment: What you exactly want ?

Comment: I want that after hover out span did not disappear when I clicked or writing inside text box but when i am not writing then it will disappear on hover out and appear on hover in@Shree

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#101").mouseenter(
  function(){ $("#spn1").css("color", "red").show();
   });
$("#101").mouseleave(
  function(){ $("#spn1").css("color", "red").hide();
   });
   

});
</script>


<input type="text" id="101"><span style="display:none;" id="spn1">limit 0-100</span>
```

Comment: It is working same as mine Nothing different @vimal

Comment: on your snippet the hover out wont hides the span